# Question about the use of 中 (first or fourth tone)?

Tags: grammar, tones

I'm unsure whether the 中 in this phrase is to be in the first or fourth tone:

吃得苦中苦，方为人上人.

Also, what exactly does 方 mean in this saying?

Thank you, 
Rachel

Comment: 中zhong１（from meaning derived from context)

see jukuu：


1.  "If you wish to be the best man, you must be prepared to suffer the Bitterest of the Bitter"
 吃得苦中苦,方为人上人
 
-- 来源 -- 英汉 - 翻译样例 - 习语  好评(10)  差评(0)   
  
2.  Hardship increases stature
 吃得苦中苦方为人上人, for possible meanings of 方 see dictionaries and above translations

Comment: 方：始：(to begin; to start; then; only then)，details at http://chengyu.xpcha.com/b57n61ckxal.html

Answer (score 3):

it's zhōng, according to 國語辭典:

http://dict.revised.moe.edu.tw/cgi-bin/cbdic/gsweb.cgi?o=dcbdic&searchid=Z00000120693

in cantonese, it jung1 (sydney lay scheme)

[http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=中](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E4%B8%AD)

sound file: http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/sound/zung1.Mp3

方者﹒才也﹒始也; roughly "only then"

have fun :)

Answer (score 2):

First tone, when you use it to mean 'middle', 'middle of', 'centre'.

When it is pronounced in the fourth tone, it typically means "got it". For example, when you check your lottery ticket and you've won.

I double checked with this [Source](http://yun.dreye.com/dict_new/dict.php) and it looks like I got it. Here are more specifics:

> 拼音: zhong (first tone)
>   注音: ㄓㄨㄥ
>   center; middle
>   in; inside; among
>   in between
>   average, mean, or middle (class, grade, etc.)
>   in the course of
>   fit for
>
> 拼音: zhong (4th tone)
>   注音: ㄓㄨㄥˋ
>   to hit (a target)
>   to suffer; to sustain
>   以上來源於：《漢英大辭典》